# Tunneling in Infinite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

In quantum mechanical tunneling particle doesn't scale the potential but instead find a short route to cross barrier. Then why is tunneling only possible in case of finite square well potential and not in infinite well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't a particle penetrate an infinite potential barrier?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449333/)

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving tunneling problems, we typically look for wavefunctions that exist as solutions to Schrodinger's equation in three regions: on one side of the well, in the middle of the well, and on the other side of the well. We then try to match the wavefunctions and their derivatives at the boundaries between the regions to see what the overall possibilities can be.

With an infinite potential, the only possible wavefunction in the barrier region is $\psi=0$. The matching conditions then force any wavefunction on one side of the barrier to completely reflect off of the barrier and stay on the same side, with no probabilitiy of tunneling through the barrier.